# LaTex fails to generate a pdf for a c-code header file

Tags: pdftex, doxygen

**What I'm using:**
I've use two different distributions of latex and the result is the same. Currently I'm using the latest version of the MikTex distribution:

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.1 (MiKTeX 20.11)
© 1982 D. E. Knuth, © 1996-2020 Hàn Thế Thành
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019
compiled with curl version 7.72.0; using libcurl/7.72.0 Schannel
compiled with expat version 2.2.10; using expat_2.2.10
compiled with jpeg version 9.4
compiled with liblzma version 50020052; using 50020052
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 3.1.4; using LibreSSL 3.1.4
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.2; using 4.2
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.4
compiled with xpdf version 4.02
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

**What I'm doing:**
I'm using Doxygen in conjunction with latex to create a pdf that documents a c-code header file.

**What's going wrong:**
After running doxygen I then call make in the latex output directory. Latex then stops with the following error output:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.767 \end{DoxyEnumFields}
```

What's strange is even if I remove all of the enumerations in an attempt to find the doxygen comment that is causing the error, the error changes:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.596 \end{longtabu}
```

And if I continue to remove code blocks I pretty much end up with nothing left and no clue as to what's causing the error.

As an additional aside, when I try to generate a pdf using an older version of latex the pdf is generated successfully.

**Last known working version:**

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.7338 (1.40.21) (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2020 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.61.1; using libcurl/7.61.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2.6; using expat_2.2.6
compiled with jpeg version 9.3
compiled with liblzma version 50020042; using 50020042
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.8.2; using LibreSSL 2.8.2
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.7348; using 4.7348
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 16.7346; using 16.7346
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6882; using 1.6882
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 8.7350; using 8.7350
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.2
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

-Matt

Comment: tabu is pretty broken but we did work with the doxygen maintainers to patch in a workaround for most cases, but it's not really possible to say anything given the information you show, other than the generated latex has mis-matched braces.  The miktex header isn't really relevant you would most likely see the same error from texlive or any tex distribution.

Comment: The remark from @DavidCarlisle is correct. Doxygen ships with some files changes to overcome this problem (as of doxygen version 1.8.16). Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me on this. I managed to discover that the issue was due to using _ in the input file name. Is this a potential bug?

Comment: As you didn't answer which version of doxygen you are using it is hard to tell. Furthermore a small doxygen project showing the problem would also help to shine a light on it.

Comment: The problem is definitely caused due to the version of doxygen you are using and the newer version of LaTeX. I didn't get the `\end{DoxyEnumFields}` but till doxygen version 1.8.16 I got the `\end{longtabu}` message. In version 1.8.17 and up the error is gone. The fact that when removing the `_` from the filename solved your problem is sheer luck! The only possible advise is upgrade your doxygen version to the current 1.8.20 version.

Comment: @albert, No dice, the issue still exists even when I upgrade to doxygen 1.8.20

Comment: @albert; I created a small doxygen project as you suggested that causes the issue I am seeing. What would be the best way for me to attach it to this thread?

The software versions I am using are:
Doxygen 1.8.20
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.1 (MiKTeX 20.11)

Comment: The best is to create  an issue in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new/choose I don't know what the size of the example is, when small you can add the source code to this question as well as well as the output of `doxygen -x` (giving the settings different from the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

My original solution was incorrect. When I upgraded to the latest version of doxygen (1.8.20) in conjunction with MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.1 (MiKTeX 20.11) the problem still exists.

**Incorrect solution:**
I figured it out, my input file to doxygen has a filename of `tx_commands.h`.

Taking a clue from this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476831/getting-the-error-missing-inserted-in-latex) I noticed that the generated `tx__commands_8h.tex` file in the latex directory wasn't escaping the `__`.  See the Hypertarget and label entries below.

```
\raisebox{\heightof{T}}[0pt][0pt]{\index{CMD\_ADC\_CHANNELS\_0@{CMD\_ADC\_CHANNELS\_0}!tx\_commands.h@{tx\_commands.h}}\index{tx\_commands.h@{tx\_commands.h}!CMD\_ADC\_CHANNELS\_0@{CMD\_ADC\_CHANNELS\_0}}}\mbox{\Hypertarget{tx__commands_8h_a69486ad0c4d595da12aa42479799d0a0a81022dff03f2a26f7259059e9be47109}\label{tx__commands_8h_a69486ad0c4d595da12aa42479799d0a0a81022dff03f2a26f7259059e9be47109}}
```

When I removed the _ to the input file name the problem went away. Is this a potential bug?

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, it is sheer luck. See my comment with the question.

Comment: @albert, No dice, the issue still exists even when I upgrade to doxygen 1.8.20